Sidebar is being pushed under my content?
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with the layout of my website – the sidebar, instead of staying neatly alongside the main content, is inexplicably slipping underneath it. Here's the snippet of CSS code I've been tinkering with in an attempt to rectify the problem:
css
#sidebar {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252) !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    float: right !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    width: calc(25% - 20px) !important;
}

I've tried Googling solutions, but none of them seem to resolve the issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
UPDATE: I think I fixed this problem! If you could take a look at my website, here, and see if it's fixed, I would be incredibly grateful. Thank you!

Underneath leads to add to the z-index. Are there any parts, which cannot be seen by this?

Yeah, it's not the z-index that's just so I can see the sidebar, the sidebar is being pushed to the bottom of my page.

Do you have enough space for the sidebar to float:right?

am not too sure my website is https://www.modifiedrides.net if you could help me that would be great!

I used "#main {
float: left; /* Float the main content to the left /
width: 70%; / Adjust width as needed */
}
#sidebar {
float: right; /* Float the sidebar to the right /
width: 30%; / Adjust width as needed */
}" It seems to have fixed this issue.
